# why __HAL_RCC_USART1_CLK_ENABLE() not be called?

Tags: stm32

I am using `STM32CUBEMX` to generate codes. In the example (Examples\UART\UART_Printf) of `STM32WB55`, I did not find `__HAL_RCC_USART1_CLK_ENABLE()`. I am very confused why it is not necessary to enable USART1 clock, but we need to enable GPIOB clock?

```
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)

{

  huart1.Instance = USART1;

  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;

  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;

  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;

  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_ODD;

  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;

  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;

  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;

  huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;

  huart1.Init.ClockPrescaler = UART_PRESCALER_DIV1;

  huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;

  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)

  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetTxFifoThreshold(&huart1, UART_TXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)

  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetRxFifoThreshold(&huart1, UART_RXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)

  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  if (HAL_UARTEx_DisableFifoMode(&huart1) != HAL_OK)

  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}

static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */

  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both calls are necessary.

`__HAL_RCC_USART1_CLK_ENABLE` is invoked from `HAL_UART_MspInit` (see [stm32wbxx_hal_msp.c](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeWB/blob/master/Projects/NUCLEO-WB15CC/Examples/UART/UART_Printf/Src/stm32wbxx_hal_msp.c)), which in turn is invoked from `HAL_UART_Init`

This is the way, how library and Cube samples are organized. Higher level code fills main descriptor (`huart1` in your case) with pointer to the periphery instance, base initialization parameters and calls the `Init` function with this descriptor. The `Init` function performs register initialization, but first calls the `MspInit` function, that must be implemented in the application code. The `MspInit` function performs additional initialization like enabling clocks, GPIO configuration, etc. All what doesn't fit a library code

`MspInit` is also implemented as empty function with `weak` attribute in the library by default, which means any other implementation will override the default one.

Comment: When I was configuring the clock tree in STM32CUBEMX, I found some parts were highlighted, i.e., showing blue color. But others only showed gray color. Does this mean the highlighted parts are enabled? If so, why the USART1 was not highlighted, since USART1 can work? I am very confused about this.

Comment: Blue highlight in the clock configuration means that value is correct. Change PLL confuguration to some insane value, and most boxes will turn red. And I'm not sure about your experience with USART1 highlihts, when I've enabled USART1 on the Pinout page, box `To USART1` has turnet blue on the Clock page and clock source selection was enabled too.